# Maples method for finding the area of a shape

Tags: geometry, area, maple

I have been given an assignment on irregular shapes in which I have to find the area of a shape using the Monte Carlo method, Simpson's Rule and Maples Method.  While I have been able to find how to do the Monte Carlo method and Simpson's Rule, I have been unable to find any real information on how to do Maples' Method.

Any information on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While Monte Carlo and Simpson's rule are specific algorithms, *Maples Method* is probably just the implementation of the algorithm used by Maple. So you will have to check Maples manuel to see how they are doing this.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into that